# How to find an effective spring constant of a quadratic potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential, spring

If a potential energy is given like $U(r)=A^3/r^2+2B^3r$, how do I find the effective spring constant using [Taylor Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)?

I compared spring constant $k$ to be equal to second derivative of potential energy with respect to $r$.

Am I going in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1):

Given the potential $U(r)=A^3/r^2 + 2B^3 r$, the effective spring constant can be defined as the second derivative of $U(r)$ evaluated at the equilibrium point. Hence,

$$U''(r)= \frac{6A^3}{r^4}$$

If $r_0$ is our equilibrium point, then $k_{\mathrm{eff}} = 6A^3/r^4_0$. Another way to perform the calculation is to compute the Taylor Series about the equilibrium point $r_0$, obtaining,

$$U(r) = \left( \frac{A^3}{r^2_0} + 2B^3 r_0 \right) + \left(2B^3 - \frac{2A^3}{r^3_0} \right)(r-r_0) + \frac{3A^3 (r-r_0)^2}{r^4_0} + \mathcal{O}(r-r_0)^3$$

If we compare the $r^2$ order term to $\frac{1}{2}k_{\mathrm{eff}}(r-r_0)^2$, we obtain the same result, $k_{\mathrm{eff}} =6A^3 /r^4_0$. From a geometric point of view, we are defining the spring constant as the curvature of the potential at the equilibrium point, which is a minimum of the potential, and by the second derivative test, $k_{\mathrm{eff}} \geq 0$.

Comment: +1, why analogous and not equal. i.e why $k \sim 6A^3/r^4_0$ and not $k = 6A^3/r^4_0$?

Comment: @NikosM. Well, it's an effective spring constant; at the minimum of the potential, $r_0$, we're treating it as if it were a simple harmonic oscillator. I guess you could write $k_{\mathrm{eff}}=6A^3/r^4_0$.

Comment: yes i understand it is the ambiguity of the **true** $k$ and the **effective** $k$, but i would say the effective is sought here, so the equal sign would be better

Comment: @NikosM. Fine, I'll be verbose and write $k_{\mathrm{eff}}=...$ :)